# Выбор строк в запросе, до тех пор, пока сумма полей не станет больше определенной

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с полями `id` и `цена`. Надо вытягивать поля `id` из этой таблицы, до тех пор, пока общая сумма этих цен не будет равна определённому значению.

Comment: А в каком порядке?

Comment: и надо подобрать такие id, чтоб сумма точно была равна, или насобирать по порядку, пока станет больше или равна

Answer (score 2):

Этот запрос будет считать сумму цен, до тех пор, пока она не станет больше или равна определенного значения. (В этом примере, значение - 400).

```
select null as id, null as price_sum
  from dual
 where (@total := 0)
 union
select id, @total := @total + price as total
  from tbl
 where @total < 400;
```

[Вот демо на SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96f52/3/0)

Comment: на сайте sqlfiddle.com можно получить результат в виде *markdown* (выпадающий список рядом с кнопкой «run query»), который можно скопировать и вставить в ответ. только у них там [баг, который они до сих пор не исправили](https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle2/pull/23/files), и надо руками вставлять пустую строку перед таблицей с результатами каждого select-а.

Answer (score 0):

А чем плохо просто в лоб?

```
select id 
  from 
     (select id, @sum:=@sum+price sum 
        from t1, 
             (select @sum:=0) s) total 
  where sum <= 400
```